# How to access server Database from Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

Can I access My own Database(on my server) using Facebook API's or its just not possible as Facebook wont allow to use Database from other web server.
I want to create an facebook application that will take all the info from friends profile and save it in my database(i.e on my server).
Actually i have not worked on any Facebook application, its just a Doubt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create an facebook
>   application that will take all the
>   info from friends profile and save it
>   in my database(i.e on my server).

That is possible and you can save into your databse but be aware of [facebook privacy policy](http://www.facebook.com/policy.php).

Comment: Hey! thanks @sAc! ...can i also fetch the content from, My Wall and store It in my Database??

Comment: @Harish: Yes you can but make sure to read privacy policy any time :)

Comment: to @sAc... can it be possible to create chat application....that logs all the chat message in my database...